# In python I am not able to export the output in text format

Tags: python, text, export

I have two string and I am trying to match each position and providing a symbol accordingly. I am very new to python and facing an issue with exporting the file. I am getting output but when I am exporting the same it gave None as out. The string look like this.

```
def up():
    for i in range (s3):
        if bp1[i]==bp2[i]:
            print("(", end="")
        else:
            print(".", end="")
ax = up()
with open('putt.txt', 'w') as a:
print(ax, file = a)
```

Comment: (1) Your function is not taking in any argument , where are you getting `s3`,`bp1` and `bp2` inside your function from. (2) your function is not returning anything, so what does `ax=up()` mean? (3) The print function will print only to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function doesn't return anything. return the string
then write and lopp should run for length of bp1 :

```
bp1 = "ASDFGHJKL"
bp2 = "AS_FG_JKL"

def up():
    data = ""
    for i in range (len(bp1)):
        if bp1[i]==bp2[i]:
            data = data + ")"
        else:
            data = data + "."
    return data
ax = up()
with open('putt.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in ax:
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: Dear Asif, I am looking for output like : ")).)).)))" (This is what I required in text file)
        In text file it shows "None"

Comment: then your ax must be ")).)).)))" that means : ax = ")).)).)))"

Comment: yes when I am checking ax it show the same ")).)).)))" but when I am exporting in text the text file contain None. I cross check the print(ax) it also printed "None"

Comment: print(ax) print None because ax = None

Comment: Dear friend, I will be grateful if some hint could be provided. The strings are
bp1: ASDFGHJKL
bp2: AS_FG_JKL
Ax in console showing the output. I am a newbie and need good direction.

Comment: what is s3 or what is the value of s3?

Comment: s3 is the lenght of string bp1 in this case it is 9